# QGIS Projective Transformation Algorithm

Tags: qgis, algorithm

I would need to know something more about the algorithm that Qgis (Georeferencer Plugin) uses to georeference with  projective algorithm.

I have tried to reproduce your results using other software and I do not succeed.

I like results but I need to know the parameters that are calculated for use in a subsequent process to superimpose information from various sources.